# beeware adding toga imageview to android

Tags: android, python-3.x, beeware

I am building small android project with beeware..and recently found that beeware toga GUI toolkit does not support images/imageview in android is there any tweak or other method which I can used to add image in my android project. I found one called toga-android but there is no guide. any help will be very help full to me thank you.
here is my small code snippet.

```
"""
Time Table app for salah 
"""
import toga
from toga.style import Pack
from toga.style.pack import COLUMN, ROW

class drd(toga.App):

    
    def startup(self):
        """
        Construct and show the Toga application.

        Usually, you would add your application to a main content box.
        We then create a main window (with a name matching the app), and
        show the main window.
        """
        
        self.main_box = toga.Box(style=Pack(direction=COLUMN))

        self.l_username = toga.TextInput(placeholder='User name',style=Pack(flex=1))
        self.l_password = toga.TextInput(placeholder='Password',style=Pack(flex=1))
        
        self.checkbutton = toga.Button('Log in',on_press=self.login_btn,style=Pack(padding=5))
        
        self.label_box = toga.Box(style=Pack(direction=ROW,padding=5))
        self.main_box.add(self.label_box)
        self.label_box.add(self.l_username)
        self.main_box.add(self.l_password)
        self.main_box.add(self.checkbutton)
        
        self.main_window = toga.MainWindow(title=self.formal_name)
        self.main_window.content = self.main_box
        self.main_window.show()
        
    def signup_btn(self,button):
        self.main_window.info_dialog("hi there","Hello {}".format(self.name_input.value))

    def login_btn(self,button):
        if self.l_username.value == "Imtiyaz" and self.l_password.value == "123":
            self.home()

        else:
            self.main_window.info_dialog("User name or Password is incorrect!")
            self.home()

    def home(self):
        self.main_box = toga.Box(style=Pack(direction=COLUMN, background_color='#7ed6c6'))
        self.hello = toga.Label('Hello there!')
        self.img = toga.ImageView(id='images',image='./resources/drd.png')
        self.main_box.add(self.hello)
        self.main_box.add(self.img)
        self.main_window = toga.MainWindow(title="app")
        self.main_window.content = self.main_box
        self.main_window.show()

def main():
    return drd()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could successfully launch an early test app I'm (re)building with BeeWare/Toga on an emulator and an amazon-HD-10 tablet using ***this*** list of imports:

```
import toga
from toga import App, Box, MainWindow
from toga import ImageView, Image
from toga.style import Pack
from toga.style.pack import COLUMN, ROW, BOTTOM, TOP, LEFT
import sys                 # <==  that one's just to exit() the app...
```

***Maybe you forgot a crucial import?***

There are 2 overlapping pics of briefcase's SDK emulator on the left side of the screenshot below.
(To make ImageViews "clickable" I had to use a pull request fork that's *NOT* merged into Toga yet -- and possibly never will...)

(Here's a [link to my github discussion](https://github.com/beeware/toga/discussions/1372) about Toga's ImageView. Smaller pics to the right are from a JS version, originally made for a Sony-PRS 500 eBook reader, 16 shades of grey)

. . . [***Youtube video of advanced WORKING APP in emulator***](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8PMUxJGSTpo)

```
 ===============================================
```

[image]